# Using the Android KeyStore to store user authentication credentials

Tags: android, authentication, keystore, fingerprint, android-keystore

I am experimenting with user authentication methods (fingerprint to be exact) and I'm also looking into the Android `KeyStore`. I am trying to build a system that allows the user to set up a fingerprint that will log a user in to my server. Currently, the server requires a POST request which requires a valid username/password combo.

I have a few questions about how this will work, because I have only a beginner's understanding of how the `Fingerprint` API and `KeyStore` work.

1) When I am prompting for a fingerprint and get a successful response back (which is easy enough to accomplish) - How can I translate that to a valid username/password so I can kick off my POST request? Do I need to store both the username and password into the `KeyStore`?

2) How exactly would that look when I am setting up the `KeyStore`? Would I need to set an alias for both the username and password? "myapp_user", "myapp_pass" for example?

3) How can I store the values for username and password into the `KeyStore`?

4) Am I even approaching this problem the right way? Is there a better way to link a fingerprint to a username/password combination securely?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The AndroidKeyStore has changed a lot in between 4.4 and current versions (in the beginning only RSA keys could be stored). Therefore you should always note what minimal SDK you are targeting.

Comment: Fair enough @Robert . My question was in regards to targeting API 23, but I would also be interested in learning how to handle this on <23 for greater user reach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general process for using the AndroidKeystore is that you generate a key in the AndroidKeyStore. That key will never leave the keystore (can't be exported) but you can use it as long as you use specific algorithms (not all are supported). You can see [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html#SupportedAlgorithms) which Android version supports what encryption type.

On Android API 23+ you can directly generate an AES key (in der AndroidKeyStore) and use that AES key for encrypting your use data like the user credentials you mentioned.

Before API23 additional steps are required: First generate an RSA key in the AndroidKeyStore, then generate an random AES key outside of the AndroidKeystore (as AES inside is not supported). Then encrypt the generated AES key with the RSA key you have generated in the AndroidKeyStore and save the encrypted AES key into the private app data directory.

Afterwards you can like in option 1 encrypt the user credentials with the generated AES key.

Comment: I guess my problem is more about understanding the process. I am easily able to create a new alias and generate a public/private key pair. But where do I store the username and password? Do I encrypt the values and put them into SharedPreferences or something? What is the standard practice? I had thought that I was actually placing the username and password into the KeyStore, and requiring a key to return them. Maybe I have the wrong idea of what the KeyStore is supposed to be doing.

Comment: For reference, I've check out the following examples in my searches.
http://www.androidauthority.com/use-android-keystore-store-passwords-sensitive-information-623779/
https://www.sitepoint.com/securing-your-android-apps-with-the-fingerprint-api/
First example just encrypts/decrypts text but doesn't store it anywhere.
Second example stores encrypted text into SharedPreferences.

Comment: @h_k: A keystore is for storing cryptographic keys. You can't save arbitrary data in it. If you want to protect data encrypt it as I described it and store it somewhere (preferences for example). Don't save the used AES key (API23+) respectively save it RSA encrypted for Android up to API23.

Comment: The linked example is not bad but it has some major drawback: If the data to be protected is getting longer (>200 bytes) the RSA encryption will fail! Therefore the intermediate step with AES. An AES key is always small enough...

Comment: Thank you, I'll accept your answer as it has cleared up some things for me. I think I have a good idea of what I need to do from here.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same kind of requirement.Below are the steps.

1. While registering for fingerprint option user will be providing the username password and then the fingerprint.
2. We need to generate key in android store and pass that to server(username, password and the key generated).
3. In server they will save this key corresponding to the username and password.
4. Whenever the user tries to login with finger pint, from client side we need to take the key once fingerprint authentication is successful and pass that to server.
5. In server they will check the table row(server DB) in which that key is already been saved and will use that corresponding username and password.

My doubt is will that key remains the same. We are passing the key to server side while registering for fingerprint t along with username password. So if again when the user tries to login and creates a key will it remain the same.